# Locust - does it have a detailed csv report

Tags: locust

Evaluating Locust load testing (in comparison to some of my older goto's).

Question:  Does Locust have a feature to output a 'detailed csv report' that has each transaction and metrics with that transaction (rather than the aggregates)?

i.e.
timestamp,test_name,url,response_size,latency,connect_time,ttfb,etc....?

Reason is to support performance problem solving with details (specifically latency break-down into what contributed to it the most: connect time/sslhandshake, time to first byte, etc) in each transaction to spot trends and potential problem areas.  I tried csv-full-history, but that looks the same as stats_history just with more aggregates.

Comment: when cross checking, supporting statement from https://jtlreporter.site/docs/integrations/locust -- "Some of the metrics wont be available with Locust.io as it does not provide them, eg: latency, connection time and others"

Answer (score 1):

Locust doesn't have these metrics out of the box with the built-in Users. Locust can run whatever code you want, though, so you can create your own users that report these metrics and report them how you want.

If you can get the metrics you want from the Requests library, you can use the regular HttpUser and [track and report them as custom metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76211765/7355637). If you can't get them from Requests, you can make your own User with a custom client as if you were [testing other systems or protocols](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html) and Locust can run whatever code you need it to (as long as it's gevent compatible). Either way if you want, you can [extend the web UI to show your custom metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76327959/7355637) or offer a download of a CSV you generate.